# Conditionnal 'changed_when' based on output in a 'with_items' task

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a simple shell task which is feed `with_items`. I want to have the '*changed*' status only when the run actually did something. So for that I have to parse the output and look for a «*Done*».

The issue is using a `register` at the same time that the `with_items` generates a list of results. And I don't find a way to access the `stdout` of the current loop iteration.

```yaml
---
- name: Test to set changed status only on when output match with 'Done'
  hosts: my-host-01
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Task doing stuff
      shell: |
        echo {{ item }}
      register: do_stuff
      with_items:
        - "Doing... Done!"
        - "Nothing to do"
      #changed_when: do_stuff.results[{{ item.id }}].stdout.find('Done')

    - name: Print 'do_stuff' var to debug
      debug:
        var: do_stuff
    - name: Try to access to the desired stdout
      debug:
        var: do_stuff.results[0].stdout
```

The expected result that I want would be:

```
TASK [Task doing stuff]
*************************************************************************
changed: [cnode02] => (item=Doing... Done!)
Ok: [cnode02] => (item=Nothing to do)
```

Comment: The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925282/iteration-using-with-items-and-register) didn't help me as it process it in the next task which is too late to update the task status I assume.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43487756/2795592

Comment: That's also done in 2 tasks. It will not help me to have the correct status of my initial task.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the following example from the ansible documentation was very helpful to understand it:

> During iteration, the result of the current item will be placed in the
>   variable:
>
> ```
> - shell: echo "{{ item }}"
>   with_items:
>     - one
>     - two
>   register: echo
>   changed_when: echo.stdout != "one"
> ```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop

In your case the condition with `stdout.find(...)` will not work. I successfully tested it with `'"string" in var.stdout'`:

```
- name: Task doing stuff
  shell: |
    echo {{ item }}
  register: do_stuff
  with_items:
    - "Doing... Done!"
    - "Nothing to do"
  changed_when: '"Done" in do_stuff.stdout'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example works using the `changed_when:` condition, for each item separately.

```yaml
- name: Task doing stuff
  shell: |
    echo {{ item }}
  register: task_result
  with_items:
    - "Doing... Done!"
    - "Nothing to do"
  changed_when: task_result.stdout | regex_search('Done')
```

In your task, you must use `register:` to store the result, e.g. `register: task_result`. During execution, especially for the `changed_when:` and `failed_when:` conditions, this is directly available via the variable name, i.e. via `task_result.stdout`.

Here you can now e.g. search for the desired text via function `regex_search( )`, or also for a certain line of the output. To search for a whole line, the function offers `multiline=True` as another parameter. More information about the function `regex_search( )` can be found in the [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions).

As soon as the task with all its items has been executed, the result (as you assumed) is available in the variable `task_result` (i.e. under the same name) as a list via the key `results`, i.e. via `task_result.results[ITEM_ID].stdout`.